# Why can't my haxe / openfl app install and launch on the android emulator

Tags: android, haxe, openfl

I have the following haxelibs installed

openfl 4.4.1
lime 3.4.1

I have a very basic hello world application that I've successfully tested on ios by running the following command

`openfl test ios -simulator -Dsource-header=haxe`

If I run the following command `openfl test android -emulator` everything seems to work and the emulator does launch however the openfl application doesn't seem to install and launch and the console is stuck waiting for the app to launch in the emulator.

I tried running `openfl setup android` so my Android sdk and ndk are install in the root /opt directory. I should also mention that I have Android studio installed. Android Studio seems to be using the same SDK and NDK directories.

Here is the console output that I get from the openfl command.

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 17.104 secs


This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.or
g/2.10/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Usage: adb devices [-l]
Starting AVD: Nexus_4_API_24
Usage: adb devices [-l]
.Usage: adb devices [-l]
```

Comment: I've never used OpenFL on HAXE, and I may ask a dumb question, but do you already have a configured emulator? Looks like the adb command to launch the emulator is not entirely correct

Comment: I have a few emulators configured. Although, openfl seems to launch an emulator that I didn't configure.

Comment: That' right, seems like there's an invalid argument or sonething

Answer (score 1):

In looking at openfl project.xml documentations I found that if you are using the `<certificate/>` and you have not defined a `path=` param then building for android will fail. So until I have a google play account with a valid cert generated I will do the following so that I can develop for both ios and android.

`<certificate team-id="" if="ios"/>`

As you can see I added the `if=` so that the cert settings will only be used when building for iOS.